# Keep leading zeros with fgetcsv in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm reading a .csv file (I have no control of the format of the file) and I'm trying to keep the leading zeros for the data in the resulting array. For instance, the .csv file has "0615" in a field, but resulting array contains "615". There are also fields in the .csv file that do not contain leading zeros, so adding zeros to the beginning of each field will not work.

I've tried to force functions to read the fields as a string, but explode, str_getcsv, fgetcsv all parse it as an integer and remove the leading zero beforehand. Any thoughts?

Edit: explode does NOT remove the leading zeros. Using explode with fgets works.

Comment: I do not have this behavior at all, `str_getcsv("001,002")` keeps leading zeros for me. What PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode()` works on a string basis; your type conversion must be happening elsewhere:

```
$data = "00555,00666,00777,00888";
$a = explode(",",$data);
foreach($a as $b) echo $b . " ";         // 00555 00666 00777 00888
```

Use `(string)$b` if PHP insists on interpreting the strings as integers.

Comment: You are correct. There was a problem with the .csv file, I assumed explode removed the leading zeros. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful using `explode` -- it doesn't know about quoted commas. If one of your values might be something like "XYZ, Inc." this is going to blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_pad`](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to add the leading zeros to the parsed integer, wherever you need it.

---

Or use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), if you are familiar with it.

```
$num = 1;
$num = sprintf('%04d', $num);
//               ^^
//               ||_ How many leading digits?
//               |_ Leading digit?
// output: 0001
```

Comment: Well the problem with that is there's no way to determine when leading numbers are needed, except by looking at the original .csv data, which can't be done once the field is parsed.

Comment: @user978887 Can't you do a `preg_replace` before doing the explode, so you can add a special character in place of `0`, then replace them back with `0`?

Comment: Ended up being a problem with the .csv file, however this solution was working with some data I was testing before I realized the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the leading zeroes for presentation or uniform formatting processes then it might be easier to simply pad the numbers when you output them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php should be of help here.

Comment: The numbers are actually sent to a database, where this field represents a unique value. I need 0615 to be different from 615 and 00615.